# Proper use of Flask-ldap

Tags: python, flask, ldap, flask-login

I am currently trying to use Flask-LDAP for authentication purposes for Sandman. Unlike normal python LDAP where the documentation is pretty straight forward, this is pretty offbase.

Example from documentation.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.ldap import LDAP, login_required
from flask.ext.pymongo import PyMongo
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True

app.config['LDAP_HOST'] = 'ldap.example.com'
app.config['LDAP_DOMAIN'] = 'example.com'
app.config['LDAP_SEARCH_BASE'] = 'OU=Domain Users,DC=example,DC=com'
app.config['LDAP_LOGIN_VIEW'] = 'custom_login'

app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'simpledb'
mongo = PyMongo(app, config_prefix='MONGO')
ldap = LDAP(app, mongo)
app.secret_key = "welfhwdlhwdlfhwelfhwlehfwlehfelwehflwefwlehflwefhlwefhlewjfhwelfjhweflhweflhwel"
app.add_url_rule('/login', 'login', ldap.login, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

This does not tell me where I can place my dn or password. So I am completely confused as to how this thing actually works.

Has anyone effectively used Flask-LDAP and if so how did you set it up? Or is there a better product out there like flask-login that I should use?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flask-login is okay and the de-facto lib for session management so you'll be needing that.

As for flask-ldap, yeah it's not well documented...

But this might be useful to you (it seems like a full feature ldap lib for flask including login helpers):
flask_ldap_login at https://github.com/ContinuumIO/flask-ldap-login